# Error: Rocket failed to launch due to failing fairings:

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

I am just learning Rust's Rocket however when I compile the code, I get errors mentioned below. I am just trying to pass values to my templates variable from my rust file.

I have a `src/main.rs` file with following code:

```
#[macro_use] extern crate rocket;
use rocket_dyn_templates::{Template, context};

#[get("/")]
fn home() -> Template{

    Template::render("index",context!{
    title : "Hello, World",
    logged_in : true,
    user_name: "test"
   })
}

#[launch]
fn rocket() -> _ {

    rocket::build()
   .mount("/", routes![home])
   .attach(Template::fairing())
}
```

Inside `templates/index.html.tera` I following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
 <header>
    <nav>
        <div>
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>
        <!-- Add navigation bar here !-->

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/about">About</a>
            </li>

            <li>
                <a href="/edit/{{title}}">Edit Page</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                {% if logged_in  %}
                 <a href="/user/{{user_name}}">{{user_name}}</a>
                 {% else %}
                 <a href="/login">Login</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
</header>

<main>
    <!-- Provide Title for your page here !-->
    <h1>{{title}}</h1>
</main>
```

however when i compile the code i am greeted with following errors:

```
41 | </html>
```

|        ^---
|
= expected tag or some content

> > Template initialization failed. Aborting launch.
> > Error: Rocket failed to launch due to failing fairings:
> > Templating
> > thread 'main' panicked at 'aborting due to fairing failure(s)',

Comment: There's no `</html>` in template you posted, is it being cut out?

Comment: @Cerberus yes it is being cut out

Comment: There's also no `</body>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are forgetting to close some tags in the html/Tera code and that is why you are getting this error.

You are forgetting to close `body`, `html`, and the `{% endif %}` for the [structure control](https://tera.netlify.app/docs/#if)

I modified the html code to something like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>{{title}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <nav>
                <div>
                    <h1>Test</h1>
                </div>
                <!-- Add navigation bar here !-->

                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/about">About</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="/edit/{{title}}">Edit Page</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        {% if logged_in  %}
                            <a href="/user/{{user_name}}">{{user_name}}</a>
                        {% else %}
                            <a href="/login">Login</a>
                        {% endif %}
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </nav>
        </header>
        <main>
            <!-- Provide Title for your page here !-->
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

and it works now